# Sequel migration ran in heroku yields postgres type error

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sequel

For some reason when I run my migrations in Heroku Sequel tries to create a row as `string` instead of `varchar`:

```
PGError: ERROR:  type "string" does not exist (Sequel::DatabaseError)
LINE 1: ...erial PRIMARY KEY, "facebook_id" integer, "email" string(50)
```

Anyone has a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok changed my migration from:

```
string  :email,                   :null => false, :unique => true
```

to

```
String  :email,                   :null => false, :unique => true
```